# Java print factorials 1-30

Tags: java, factorial

All I am trying to do is print the factorials for 
numbers 0-30.  When I run this, it endlessly prints Factorial=0.  Can someone tell me how to correct this?

```
public static void factor(){

    int n=0;
    int factorial = 1;
    while (n<=0&n<=30)
    {
        n=n++;
      factorial = factorial * n;
      n--;
      System.out.println("Factorial = " + factorial);
    }


}


public static void main(String[] args) {
   factor();
}
```

Comment: Remove `n--`. Also, `x * 0 = 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're decrementing `n` inside the loop, so it it will always flip between `0` and `1`. Additionally, an `int` can't hold numbers so large, and neither can a `long`. You'll have to use something smarter, like a [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html):

```
int n = 0;
BigInteger factorial = BigInteger.ONE;
while (n <= 30) {
    System.out.printf("Factorial(%d) = %s%n", n, factorial);
    n++;
    factorial = factorial.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(n));
}
```